# Ignore extra_float_digits parameter in JetBrains

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I try to connect to PostgreSQL database via JetBrains products (PyCharm or DataGrip) but I get

`[08P01] ERROR: unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits.`

I saw answers about `extra_float_digits` parameter in PgBouncer, but I have no access to server with PgBouncer.

Is there a way to solve this on client side?

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: As I know there is Postgres 12

Answer (score 2):

That is a pgBouncer error message, so you must be connecting through pgBouncer.

You will have to add this to `pgbouncer.ini`:

```
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
```

Comment: I saw this solution. I don't have access to pgBouncer and looking if there is a solution on my side (some driver or JetBrains options)

Comment: No. You will have to get in touch with the administrators. But the change is harmless, and it is required for all applications that use the JDBC driver.